# PHP variables and loops in HTML format

Tags: php, html, regex, variables, themes

**page.html**

```
<body>
   <h1>{{HEADING1}}</h1>  {{CONTENT1}}
   <h2>{{NEWSLETTER}}</h2>
   <h1>{{VAR1}}</h1>  {{VAR2}}
</body>
```

**page.php**

```
$HEADING    = 'Heading';
$CONTENT    = '
              <div align="center">
              -- Content goes here --
              </div>
              ';
$NEWSLETTER = 'newsletter content';
$VAR1       = 'Another Sub Heading';
$VAR2       = 'content';

$File       = file('page.html');
print $File;
```

---

**1>** While the url http://example.com/page.php executes,
All the {{VARIABLE}} should replace by the value in $VARIABLE.

**2>** Also I want to call the PHP loop inside HTML 
Something Like

```
BEGIN WHILE LOOP
CONTENTS
END
```

What are the best methods (or Regular Expression) to implement these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below can be used to change the variables $HEADING to {{HEADING}}

```
   $File          = file('file.html');
   $FContent      = join("", $File);
   $FileContent   = preg_replace("/{{(.*?)}}/e","@$$1", $FContent);

   print $FileContent;
```

Comment: This is an excellent option. Same this way, I want to use control structures also.

Answer (score 1):

what about using a template engine? See [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

you will have to set the variables in your PHP files like this

```
return array("variable" => "variable_content");
```

and then use it in the HTML files this way:

```
Content: {{variable}}
```

in the HTML you can also loop with Twig syntax

```
{% for var in variables %}
   Content: {{var}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is the Twig easy to integrate?

Comment: to be honest, I always used it by using the Symfony2 framework so I never integrated it in a web app. You should try. There's smarty also, which is another template engine. It's easy to integrate (i did it before) but not as powerfull as twig.

Comment: Ok. I was expecting regular expressions or some PHP functions. Anyway I will try Twig for personal which new to me. Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace here:

```
$File = str_replace("{{HEADING}}",$HEADING,$File);
$File = str_replace("{{CONTENT}}",$CONTENT,$File);
print $File;
```

Comment: Should be generic. Because the variables may varies and maybe a lot.