# How to stop str_replace from changing all instances in every item in the array?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I'm looping a multidimensional array with a for loop and triggering and email for every item in the loop. I want change {{fname}} to the real name from the key.

```
foreach($customermarketingarray as $key => $value){
     $customeremail = $value['email'];
     $fname = $value['first_name'];
     $body = str_replace("{{fname}}",$fname,$body);                     
                             }
```

For some reason everything is coming out unique except the {{fname}} is using the first name in the first loop for every fname in the loop. If the first person is Joe, it's making every fname Joe

Comment: Then problem with your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because  you are using one `$body` over and over again, and once the replacement has been made there is nothing more to replace. Use a fresh version of `$body` on every iteration.

```
foreach($customermarketingarray as $key => $value){
     $customeremail = $value['email'];
     $fname = $value['first_name'];
     $tempBody = str_replace("{{fname}}",$fname,$body);              
      // now use this $tempBody for display
     }
```

This way on every iteration of your loop you get a new template from `$body` again and you can make replacements to it and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the variable $body in each loop. Just use a new variable to store the result. See my example below.

```
<?php
$customermarketingarray=array(
    0=>array("email"=>"1@test.com","first_name"=>"Joe1"),
    1=>array("email"=>"2@test.com","first_name"=>"Joe2"),
    2=>array("email"=>"3@test.com","first_name"=>"Joe3"),
    3=>array("email"=>"4@test.com","first_name"=>"Joe4")
);
$body="First Name: {{fname}}<br>Email: {{email}}<br><br>";
foreach($customermarketingarray as $key => $value){
     $customeremail = $value['email'];
     $fname = $value['first_name'];
     $email = $value['email'];
     $res_body .= str_replace(array("{{fname}}","{{email}}"),array($fname,$email),$body);
}
echo $res_body;
?>
```

The result for the above code is

```
First Name: Joe1
Email: 1@test.com

First Name: Joe2
Email: 2@test.com

First Name: Joe3
Email: 3@test.com

First Name: Joe4
Email: 4@test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

First time you are using str_replace it replaces occurrences of {{fname}} in entire body. There is nothing to replace in further loop iterations.

Use preg_replace which has additional parameter (limit) which states how many replacements will be made at most. In your example if there is only one {{fname}} per each name using 1 as count parameter will do.

Read the documentation. It's pretty self explanatory.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Another thing is problem with construction of your data. You cannot distinguish, without additional rules, which {{fname}} goes to which replacement.

It is not clear whether you want to use $body as template (I've assumed as no, because you are not using $body for anything except replacement in loop iterations). My answer is valid if there are multiple occurrences of {{fname}} in body and you want to replace them one by one with names from loop iterations.

Comment: Geez... Mistaken it with preg_replace parameter - correcting my answer right away :)

Answer (score -1):

**Using preg_replace**

It can be done using preg_replace instead str_replace
Answer: [PHP variables and loops in HTML format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262002/php-variables-and-loops-in-html-format)

go through and check deprecated, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
    $body_message = $body;
    foreach($customermarketingarray as $key => $value){
         $customeremail = $value['email'];
         $fname = $value['first_name'];
        // $body = str_replace("{{fname}}",$fname,$body);  
        $body_message  = preg_replace("/{{(.*?)}}/e","@$$1", $body);                   
    }
```

**Using str_replace**

```
$body_message = $body;
foreach($customermarketingarray as $key => $value){
     $customeremail = $value['email'];
     $fname = $value['first_name'];
     $body_message = str_replace("{{fname}}",$fname,$body);                        
     }
```