# How do I include a css file into php in the head section of the page and a js file before the end of body tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to include a css file into the head section of a php file ?
Right now I am including css in this way:

```
<?php include('./includes.header.html'); ?>
<style><?php include('./test.css'); ?> </style>
```

What it does is it includes the css in the body section not in the head section.
I have no idea to add js file before the end of body tag.
Please tell me a way to include the css file in the head section and js file before the end of the body tag.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: put the css call inside `includes.header.html` and you dont want to use php  include on the css file just the call `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='test.css'>`

Comment: For what reason would you need to do this?

Comment: Maybe this will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262002/php-variables-and-loops-in-html-format

Comment: you can store the css in a variable and print in html file. Check the above link

Comment: @Dagon that is a template file. I don't want to load test.css on every file.

Comment: _"Please tell me a way to include the css file in the head section"_ - place the code that reads the content of the CSS file inside the head ... _"and js file before the end of the body tag"_ - place the code that embeds the JS before the closing body tag ... sorry, but it is totally unclear what your actual problem with that is.

Answer (score 0):

php `include` should only be used to include PHP files, not css. Edit the header HTML and add the css normally ie

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
```

You can programatically add it using PHP anywhere ie

```
<?php print_r('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">'); ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Harry, thanks for the reply. header.html is template file. So, header.html would be used at a lot of places.
But test.css would be used only on one page.
I don't want to include test.css on every page.

Answer (score 0):

According to default structure of a web page add css and js files like this

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    //your other code here
    <script src="test.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

php include can be used to add php files but for css you should use this default method.

Comment: How do I add page specific css file while keeping the template header.html the same on every page?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment about adding the styles to a specific page header: you could use a conditional with `isset` and a variable to set section-specific styles to your header like so:

```
<?php
    if (isset($section_specific_styles))
    {
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/{$section_specific_styles}.css\">";
    }
?>
```

You would then set the variable `$section_specific_styles` in the relevant page to only add the stylesheet in that page's header (thus, other pages without the variable set would not add the additional stylesheet.)